# upload image from react to a nodejs express API

Tags: node.js, reactjs

I have the following input component to upload files:

```
 <input
  name="image"
  ref={this.fileInputRef}
  className="FileInput"
  type="file"
  multiple
  onChange={onFilesAdded}
/>
```

and this the content of onFilesAdded method:

```
if (file.length > 1) {
  setUploadingError('Solo puedes cargar un archivo');
  return;
} else {
  setSending(true);
  setUploadingError(null);

  const data = new FormData();
  data.append('file', file);

  httpService.contractPayment(data);
}
```

then on my httpService.contractPayment(data) if a fetch wrapper that make a POST request with the follwoing header:

```
{
  Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
}
```

But on nodejs I did not get the image, but If I try from postman I get the image and the image is uploaded. So thinks I have something wrong frome react. Any suggestiong please.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There can be quite a few issues here, but let's take it from the top. First, you're calling `onFilesAdded` function when your input changes, this is how you could access the file:

```
onFilesAdded = event => {
 const file = event.target.files[0]
}
```

After that, you append it to the `FormData` by adding 3 arguments:

`data.append('file', file, file.name);`

A pitfall here is if you add a `content-type` header to the request, it won't work. Let `fetch` handle all that, just add `Authorization`!

Comment: Thank you so much, my problem was that append data.append('file', file); insted of data.append('file', file[0]); but I did not see the error until I see your answer